# how to send data onClick() to another php for processing using post or get?

Tags: php

I want to send data using GET or POST to another php file on a button's(NOT Submit button) onClick() Event.
Please help me.

Comment: Give your view for HTML component for click event like label, checkbox select box.

Comment: what data you want to post. Is it if form or something else.

Comment: Hello please inform what do you want use ajax or simple get/post method

Comment: show what have you tried

Comment: I need simple GET or POST way

Comment: From date: <input type="text" id="fromdate" value="" onChange="showuser()">   To date: <input type="text" id="todate" value="" onChange="showuser()">  <input type="button" id="btn_bet_date" value="Export in excel" onClick="Location: bet_date_excel.php?fromdate&todate">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let I give you simple HTML with post method using AJAX

Test.php

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#Submit").click(function() {
                    var value = jQuery("#txt").val();
     var data=jQuery('#myform_new').serializeArray();
                    $.post('test1.php', { myform: data});
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform_new">
            <input type="text" name="abc" value="abc"  id="txt"/>
            <input type="text" name="abc1" value="abc1"  id="txt1"/>
            <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Test1.php(ajax calling file)

```html
<?php
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Let i give you some of the ajax posting method
(1)

```js
<script>
                    $(function() {
                        $("#Submit").click(function() {
                            var value = jQuery("#txt").val();
             var data=jQuery('#myform_new').serializeArray();
                            $.post('test1.php', { myform: data});
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

(2)

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $("#Submit").click(function() 
  { 
   var txt = jQuery("#txt").val(); 
   var txt1 = jQuery("#txt").val(); 
   $.post('test1.php', { txt: txt,txt1:txt1 }); return false; }); }); 
        </script>
```

(3)

```js
 <script type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $("#Submit").click(function() { 
   var txt = jQuery("#txt").val(); 
   var txt1 = jQuery("#txt").val(); 
   $.post('test1.php', { data: "txt="+txt+"&txt1="+txt1}); return false; }); }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: what if i have 2 or more values to send,will i have to write like this way:
$.post('test1.php', { myform: value,value2:value2,value3:value3 });

Comment: @DineshSuthar , you will have to read jQuery's .post() API manual page :-). The syntax is { name1: value1, name2: value2, ...nameN: valueN }. There are also jQuery functions that take the whole form and assemble the { } package for you. In PHP you will receive $_POST['name1'] and so on.

Comment: try above code now, i have changed.. using serializearray we can get all the post data in test1.php file. you will get data in array.

Comment: i used this way,is it correct:

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
                $("#btn_bet_date").click(function() {
                    var fromdate = jQuery("#fromdate").val();
      var todate = jQuery("#todate").val();
                    $.post('bet_date_excel.php', { fromdate: fromdate,todate:todate });
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello in there i have explain both ajax and get/post method, Please have look below  link for get/post method for submit a form in php.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm
This below code is used for submit form using ajax
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formoid" action="studentFormInsert.php" title="" method="post">
        <div>
            <label class="title">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="title">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit">
        </div>
 </form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get some values from elements on the page: */
      var $form = $( this ),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post */
      var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), name2: $('#name2').val() } );

      /* Alerts the results */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
      });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this:
From date: <input type="text" id="fromdate" value="" onChange="showuser()"> To date: <input type="text" id="todate" value="" onChange="showuser()"> <input type="button" id="btn_bet_date" value="Export in excel" onClick="Location: bet_date_excel.php?fromdate&todate"> 

is it correct way?

Comment: What you want exactly please explain detail Thanks.

Comment: ok,
I need,on button click of Export in Excel button,the dates selected in both of the textboxes,should go to the php file: bet_date_excel.php for further processing.